# Opening URL in WebView by clicking button

Tags: android, url, button, webview

I am making an application in which I have used three buttons which when pressed should load their respective url assigned to them in a webview but I am unable to do so.

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.widget.Button;


public class Webview extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    WebView myweb;
    Button bscore, bnews, bschedule;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);

        bscore= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonscore);
        bnews=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnews);
        bschedule= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonschedule);
        myweb= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        myweb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        myweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myweb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myweb.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
        bscore.setOnClickListener(this);
        bnews.setOnClickListener(this);
        bschedule.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonscore:
            myweb.loadUrl("http://m.cricketworld.com/live-scores/");
            break;
        case R.id.buttonnews:
            myweb.loadUrl("http://m.cricketworld.com/live-news/");
            break;
        case R.id.buttonschedule:
            myweb.loadUrl("http://m.cricketworld.com/live-schedule/");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ourViewClient.java code is given below

```
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url){
        v.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: your problem is not clear, plz paste logcat if you are having any exception.

Comment: Use permisson  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> and still you get some error post  logcat

Comment: "I am unable to do so" -- please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely what you mean** by this.

Comment: I tried your code myself and its working fine. I tested on it on Emulator. I got response for score URL, however I am getting error for remaining two urls.

Comment: @RiteshGune i am not getting any error... the application runs fine but when i click the buttons they don't load any url.

Comment: @ArunCThomas i have used permission too but still the problem persists

Comment: post  your layout file

Comment: I can't see any problem with the code. But if you are using a API newer that API 3, you may face some problems. You can avoid it with using some annotations.